# backward filter and many to many relationship

Tags: powerbi

I have been really struggling with this for the past week. Let me explain what is it that I'm trying to do and maybe you can help:

- A forecast is made for 1 product only. It has a date and volume to be ordered
- A product can have many forecasts
- Each product is made out of many intermediates (ingredients) using percentages totaling to 100%:
  *Example: product A = 15% intermediate 1 + 45% intermediate 2 + 40% intermediate 3*

How can I create a table or chart showing the following:

monthly volumes for each intermediate (intermediate volume = product volume x intermediate percent for that product)

Below is a snapshot of my current Power BI schema:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found the answer: Below is the schema:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSjhI.jpg)

I've created two meausres. The first one in the "PRODUCT" table named "Product **Volume":
Product Volume = CALCULATE(SUM(FORECAST[Volume]))**

The 2nd is in the "RECIPE" table named "Intermediate Volume":
**Intermediate Volume =
IF (
HASONEVALUE ( INTERMEDIATE[IID] ),
SUMX (
RECIPE,
RECIPE[Percent] * 'PRODUCT'[Product Volume]
),
BLANK()
)**

And this worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

For each IID, you need to iterate over each row in recipe, and multiply the relevant percent by the sum of the volume in the related forecast. So your measure looks like:

```
Intermediate Volume = 
IF ( 
    HASONEVALUE ( INTERMEDIATE[IID] ),
    SUMX ( 
        RECIPE,
        RECIPE[Percent] * SUM ( FORECAST[Volume] )
    ),
    BLANK()
)
```

Comment: Glad it helped. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Actually, I'm still getting the wrong monthly total for each intermediate. The only time I get the correct monthly total for an intermediate is when selecting a single product. Any ideas?

Comment: Add some sample data, with your expected outcome

Comment: This is the product table
PID1 Product 1 
PID2 Product 2
PID3 Product 3
PID4 Product 4

Comment: Example is: December, the forecast is:
Product 1 at 54,330 liters
Product 3 at 98,244 liters
Product 1 recipe is:
Intermediate 1 @ 25%
Intermediate 4 @ 15%
Intermediate 5 @ 40%
Intermediate 6 @ 20%

Product 2 recipe is:
Intermediate 2 @ 50%
Intermediate 3 @ 25%
Intermediate 4 @ 25%

Comment: I can't use this editor to give you the full picture. Not enough space and not enough tools are provided